Update an existing row in a SharePoint list from a Microsoft form using power automate
I am using two forms: a Requisition form and an Offer form. The Requisition form creates an item in a SharePoint list. After approvals, the Offer form is filled out, and its details are used to fill in empty fields in the SharePoint list. I am using Power Automate and need an expression to update the SharePoint list. If the confirmation number in the Offer form and the row ID in the SharePoint list match, the fields in the SharePoint list will be updated with data from the Offer form. Thank you in advance.
I have tried equals('Get_response_details')?['r1fc332e01cca42f6a52862edc11ad005'], "@triggerBody()?['FormID']")

I would make a flow triggered by the "Offer form". You should have a "Get items" action, based the Sharepoint list, where the query need to be like
ID eq '[[~OfferFormID]]'

The output of this action will be an array of one element.
Next action should be an "Update item", where the ID field should come form the ID of the previous "Get items" outcome. This will create an apply-to-each container, but will have only one item in it.
